# variation partitioning plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently performing some variation partitioning analyses using the package vegan. Although I get the plots by using the function `plot`, I would like to know if it is possible to get the plots using ggplot since I think they will be much better to use.

I m posting a reproducible example:

```
 data(mite)
 data(mite.env)
 data(mite.pcnm)
 mod <- varpart(mite, ~ ., mite.pcnm, data=mite.env, transfo="hel")
 mod

 ## Use fill colours
 showvarparts(2, bg = c("hotpink","skyblue"))
 plot(mod, bg = c("hotpink","skyblue"))
```

Could the plot be done using ggplot?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure how good it is, but a package "ggvegan" exists which seems to be aimed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using ggplot, see if you can use it on your data.

It can be easily plotted using `ggplot2` and `ggforce` package. We only need `geom_circle()` from ggforce.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

df.venn <- data.frame(x = c(3, 1),y = c(1, 1),labels = c('A', 'B'))
p <- ggplot(df.venn, aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = 1.5, fill = df.venn$labels)) +geom_circle(alpha = .5, size = 2, colour = 'grey',show.legend = FALSE ) +coord_fixed()+annotate("text", x = df.venn$x , y = df.venn$y,label=df.venn$labels ,size = 5)
p
```

[image]

```
p+annotate("text", x = 2 , y =1,label="A and B" ,size = 5)+theme_void()
```

[image]

Three circles

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
df.venn <- data.frame(x = c(3, 1, 2),y = c(1, 1,2.8),labels = c('A', 'B',"C"))
p <- ggplot(df.venn, aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = 1.5, fill = df.venn$labels)) +geom_circle(alpha = .5, size = 2, colour = 'grey',show.legend = FALSE ) +coord_fixed()+annotate("text", x = df.venn$x , y = df.venn$y,label=df.venn$labels ,size = 5)
p+annotate("text", x = 2 , y =1,label="A and B" ,size = 4)+annotate("text", x = 1.35 , y =2,label="B and C" ,size = 4)+annotate("text", x = 2.7 , y =2,label="A and C" ,size = 4)+annotate("text", x = 2 , y =1.6,label="A and B and C" ,size = 2)+theme_void()
```

[image]